# Reset a user's security information (Q&A) in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, passwords, asp.net-membership

I want to change the user's password Question and Answer by calling the method ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(userName);
string password = user.GetPassword(); // error here
string sQuestion = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
string sAnswer = txtAnswer.Text.ToString();
user.ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(password, sQuestion, sAnswer);
```

But I am an administrator; I can not pass the user's password because I do not know it.

Comment: Could you please put your provider configuration data, you probably have enablePasswordRetrieval to false and passwordFormat="hashed", if you change these you will be able to retrieve the password but it means lesser security

Comment: The simple solution is have the USER provide the password and choose the new Q&A.

Comment: The database is an existing one. It was set passwordFormat="hashed". I am upadting the application, so I can't change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already asking the user to enter data, why not ask again for the password? Then you can use that with the same code, just setting the password to the value of a text box.

```
string password = txtPassword.Text;
```

An alternative is to automatically reset the password, then ask the user to change it to a better password choice:

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(userName);
string password = user.ResetPassword();
string sQuestion = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
string sAnswer = txtAnswer.Text.ToString();
user.ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(password, sQuestion, sAnswer);
```

The latter is not a great solution because it requires additional steps to occur after this code.

Comment: I would more in favor of changing the password to a random 16 character password, change the secret question and answer, and all the user to reset the password.  Of course as you say the alternative is just annoying.

Comment: No, my program has an admin part. The user can't access it. I want an admin to reset it.